# Setting SelectedIndex on tabBarController in viewDidLoad does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having an issue trying to set the current tab for the tabBarController in which I have two views nested. When the application starts, I want to change the default tab being displayed. As a result, I am doing this out of viewDidLoad of one of the nested viewcontrollers. I can disable the tabBarController by:

```
 self.tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

and the tabBarController has an address (it exists).

I have tried a few different variations of changing the tab including:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

and

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

however neither seem to work. They work, however, when I invoke these functions through IB actions.

This is being done out of one of the nested controllers. Maybe this has to be done out of somewhere else?

Comment: Have you tried setting `selectedViewController`?

Comment: @GuyKogus I don't have direct access to that particular view controller's pointer as i have built them inside of the storyboard. Do you know a way to get a pointer to a particular view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Use the selectedIndex property on the UITabBarController.

```
 controller.selectedIndex = tabBarButtonIndex;
```

or use

```
[controller setSelectedIndex:tabBarButtonIndex];
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're calling `[super viewDidLoad]` first

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```